# Including shared powershell files in Nuget package?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have a solution that has several projects that create Nuget packages when they build.  Many of the powershell files are shared across different projects and I'm trying to come up with a good way to keep them synchronized.

My first impression was to use linked files, but come to find out, linked files don't get included in the Nuget package.  I also can't find anything on the internet about it.

I'm thinking I'm gonna have to write a custom build target, but before I go down that road, I want to see if there's an easy approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is one way...  Make the linked files as "copy to output directory".  Change the output directory in the project settings to "content".  You can keep your content directory in tact!!

Comment: Another thing, remove the dll and pdb from the content directory by doing this  nuget.exe pack Package.nuspec -Exclude Content\\*.dll;content\\*.pdb

Comment: Although if you want to include things in the tools that's a little trickier

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could move all of the plumbing PowerShell code into a module and put it in your `$env:PSModulePath`. From there, your solution-specific build scripts could just `Import-Module MyNugetStuff` and then pass in the local paths, etc. Finally, you could add your module to its own folder in your VCS (assuming you want to share) and then create a hard link between your VCS folder and your module path. Sure, all the devs on your team will have to do the same, but you could also script that and they'd only need to run it once.

Comment: Making a module is the correct way. When you want to be able to update the module version for some projects without changing others,
you need to store everything in a commonFunctions.ps1 in the projects ps1 dir. Afterwards: (PowerShell 3.0) you can use `. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot commonFunctions.ps1)`.